# iPhone 5s automatically opens applications by itself even after performing a factory reset

Tags: iphone, touchscreen

My iPhone 5s touchscreen is not working the way it should. Every time i unlock my iPhone 5s, it automatically opens applications by itself. It has been happening for the past few months. I've removed the glass protector, did a factory reset but to no avail. How can i solve this nagging issue?

Comment: You mean it opens apps that were not open last time you locked it? It is supposed to return to the same state as when locked. or do you mean you are force-quitting apps & they open… or?

Comment: @Tetsujin, it opens apps on its own without me even touching the screen.